# Tweepy (Python) and Oauth (Twitter) Problem

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
```

When I run this line of tweepy code i run into two problems. I receive the code "Tweepy has no attribute OAuthHandler" despite that being in the documentation I found. One assumes that that would be valid code.

The second problem is that when I registered my app, I did not receive a consumer_ token. I'm not quite sure how to request a consumer token either.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get both the `consumer_token` and the `consumer_secret`. When you register the app it gives you a couple of strings you then use for authentication. The `consumer_token` is the Consumer Key string twitter provides you with, and then the `consumer_secret` is the Consumer Secret twitter provides you with.

Then when you call `auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)` you have to have set both the `consumer_token` and the `consumer_secret` to the strings twitter provided you with. Then this should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have

> import tweepy

before you attempt to call any of its classes. That sounds like the main problem you are having.

1. You will need 2 sets of keys, the consumer keys, and the access tokens. Both are available on the https://dev.twitter.com/apps page where you have your registered app. The consumer keys are used by the OAuthHandler(), and the access tokens are used by set_access_token(). Please see [this example of using OAuthHandler](https://github.com/nloadholtes/tweepy/blob/nloadholtes-examples/examples/oauth.py)